# Problems with urinary incontinence

Tags: salat, wudu, incontinence

I am suffering from urinary incontinence, but it doesn't happen all the time. It only happens sometimes every day and I can't predict when it happens.

Whenever I pray I insert a pad and start praying. However, I do panic, wondering if I leaked urine and must repeat everything again because all I want is to just manage to achieve perfect prayer without so much struggle. I want to be like other muslims.

When I finish salah, I check the pad. If there is urine in it, meaning I leaked, I repeat wudu and pray again. I keep on doing that until the pad after prayer is clean.

Am I doing the right thing? Should I continue like this or should I learn to ignore to check the pad?

Comment: It may be too much cold (cold can cause urinary incontinence), what did your doctor tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have been legally established as having urine incontinence then you are only required to do wudu at the start of each prayer and if anything leaks it won’t break your prayer. This is different from urinating as you cannot control when it comes out. During this period you can offer salah and nafl prayers but the wudu becomes invalid at the time of the next prayer so you need to do a new one.

However if it happens after you urinate try to urinate a couple hours before salah time begins to ensure you reduce the leakage. There’s no need to keep checking the pad once the above has been established but if you feel you need to then do so but try to avoid it as this could lead to waswas (satanic whispers)

Source- https://islamqa.org/hanafi/seekersguidance-hanafi/32817/urinary-incontinence-and-wudu/

Comment: Thank you brother. I have not been to a doctor and been diagnozed as having urinary incontinence. I am feeling quite ashamed of it.

My urinary incontinence is not so connected with urinating. Sometimes it happens even after three hours of peeing. I can't control it but I wish with my whole heart Allah will cure me of this bc I just want to do wudu and pray like a normal person

Comment: There’s no need to feel ashamed, I also suffer from it and It mentally had an affect on me. But after a while I realised that this is a test Allah is putting me through so there’s no need to panic, just make duaa and do your best.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You’re welcome :)