# Disabled and namaz

Tags: salat, disability

Salaam sisters and brothers.

I've been trying to get help regarding this issue I have since being a child and wondering if you could help.

I am 22 years old and I am disabled wheelchair bound. My question is not a question but more of a issue I need help with.

I was never really taught about Islam growing up, my family just expected us to know how to pray etc. my family always told me I didn't have to do namaz because of my issues but as I got older they told me I should be praying but I have a lot of reasons as to why I'm not praying.

I have incontinence problems, I don't go two minutes without having an accident and if I do wudo it breaks two minutes later.

I can't perform wudo properly as I can't really wash my arms legs and face properly as I can't reach them.

I can't wear a hijab or appropriate clothing on my own so I'm not sure what I would do when I'm praying as I've got no help to wear clothing, I also can't cover my feet.

Lastly due to my disabilities I don't really know how to pray. I don't know what to say or when to lift my arms up or not. It's embarrassing but this is why I'm seeking help.

Comment: Please see https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/71686/56455 and https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/38233/56455

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with urinary incontinence](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/71666/problems-with-urinary-incontinence)

Answer (score 1):

About ability, please note this rule:

> Issue 376: When one becomes disabled from standing during the prayer,
> it is obligatory to sit. When one is disabled also from sitting also,
> it is obligatory to lie down. However, it is obligatory that nothing
> be recited as long as the body is not still.

[reference](https://www.al-islam.org/summary-rulings-naser-makarem-shirazi/rules-prayer)

"You said, 'I don't really know how to pray". You should learn to pray, as not knowing is not accepted on Judgment Day. There are different resources available for learning.

About wudu and wearing Hijab, you should seek assistance from someone else.

You said your wudu breaks within two minutes. Okay, two minutes is enough for one prayer. But you should pray the minimum required. I.e., you should omit the Mustahab parts of prayer. For the next prayer, you should renew your wudu. [Reference](https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa21404)

Comment: I have nobody to help me perform wudu and I don't know how to pray because I was never taught and I know that's not an excuse however I do know how to pray al fatiah so that's what I pray for all my namaz. My wudu breaks in the middle of namaz and I feel wrong if I continue so I stop. Is there a video or website that can teach me how to pray because I'm desperate to learn.

Comment: @NoName [here you can find](https://www.al-islam.org/tags/salah-prayers) different media and resources to learn Prayer: